# remove rows containing matching numeric strings

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub

I have a dataframe that has 3 columns:

```
df

A             B               C
round1    test1        testing1
round1    test1        testing2
round1    test1        testing3
round1    test1        testing4
round1    test1        testing5
round2    test2        testing1
round2    test2        testing2
round2    test2        testing3
round2    test2        testing4
round2    test2        testing5
.
.
.
.
.
round100  test30       testing30
round100  test30       testing31
```

How do I remove the rows where the numeric values in the strings of column `B` and `C` match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the numeric part and compare them.

```
NumB = sub("\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", DAT$B)
NumC = sub("\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", DAT$C)
DAT = DAT[NumB != NumC,]
```

## DATA

```
DAT = read.table(text="A       B     C
round1    test1        testing1
round1    test1        testing2
round1    test1        testing3
round1    test1        testing4
round1    test1        testing5
round2    test2        testing1
round2    test2        testing2
round2    test2        testing3
round2    test2        testing4
round2    test2        testing5",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the non-digits, `"\\D"`, with the empty string and compare what is left:

```
subset(DF, gsub("\\D", "", B) != gsub("\\D", "", C))
```

giving this where the input `DF` is shown reproducibly below in the Note:

```
          A      B         C
2    round1  test1  testing2
3    round1  test1  testing3
4    round1  test1  testing4
5    round1  test1  testing5
6    round2  test2  testing1
8    round2  test2  testing3
9    round2  test2  testing4
10   round2  test2  testing5
12 round100 test30 testing31
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
A             B               C
round1    test1        testing1
round1    test1        testing2
round1    test1        testing3
round1    test1        testing4
round1    test1        testing5
round2    test2        testing1
round2    test2        testing2
round2    test2        testing3
round2    test2        testing4
round2    test2        testing5
round100  test30       testing30
round100  test30       testing31"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```